# RedBeanPHP и PHP switch: case

Tags: php, .htaccess, switch, redbeanphp, case

Есть рабочий вариант кода страницы, для вывода текста из БД с помощью RedBeanPHP:

```
<?php
    require_once('db.php');

    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
    $page = R::load('pages', $id);

    switch ($id) {

    case $id:

    $title = $page->page_title;
?>
    <h2><?php echo $page->page_h2; ?></h2>
    <h3><?php echo $page->page_h3; ?></h3>
    <?php echo $page->content; ?>
    <h4><?php echo $page->page_h4; ?></h4>
<?php
    exit;
}
```

В нем происходит вывод текста на страницу из БД, он рабочий. Только лишь УРЛ неудобный.

В БД, каждой странице приписан свой page_url, хотелось быть именно с помощью page_url: /page.php?id=page_url обращаться к странице, а не как сейчас /page.php?id=1 и т.д.

Далее в .htaccess я буду использовать: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
чтобы получить более красивый УРЛ, вида /page_url

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: В ответе указал ссылки на видео уроки. Не поленитесь и посмотрите. Это достаточно обширная тема и говорить на нее я могу с вами очень долго. На stackoverflow не очень удобно излагать полностью свои мысли) Но плейлист уроков рекомендую посмотреть, сам по ним учился)

Comment: Как раз такие тема "красивый УРЛ, вида /page_url" разъесняется в тех уроках

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$id = '';
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
```

Можно не инициализировать переменную, потому что в следующей строчке вы ее сразу же переопределяете.

`$_GET['id']` - если вы захотели использовать цитирую " буквенным $page_url, которые присвоены каждой странице", то для общего понятия можно использовать `$_GET['alias']`, т.к. это подходит к логике вашего приложения. Соответственно и хранить в базе поле с названием `alias` и в GET параметре указывать `page.php?alias=my_web_page` - момент не основной, но чтобы не писать "плохой" код, понятный вам же, думаю данная замена будет полезной.

`if ($page->id == '0' && $page->id == 'null')`

В первом условии `$page->id == '0'` вы используете проверку

1. В Переменной `$page` может быть значение `NULL`, которое вам присвоит метод redbean, если не найдет, это означает что будет вызвана ошикбка уровня `E_NOTICE`, говорящая о том что вы обращаетесь к переменной объекта, когда объект равен `NULL`
2. Вы в переменную `$page` загружаете данные из БД, с помощью метода `R::load('pages', $id)` - который грузит данные по индентефикатору записи. Если вы хотите использовать "алиас" страницы, то должны использовать метод `R::find('pages', 'alias = ?', [$alias])`, если ваш "алиас" действительно уникален, то вы без проблем получите одну запись и она сохранится в `$page`.
3. Я бы использовал такой подход:

   ```
   if(!$page = R::find('pages', 'alias = ?', [$alias])) {
       header("Location: 404");
   }
   ```

**Советую** так же убрать конструкцию switch-case, т.к. она совершенно бесполезная **в данной ситуации**, потому что ваш *будущий* `$alias` будет принимать **только одно** значение, просто уберите ее и следуйте советам, которые я описал **ниже**.

На счет ЧПУ. Можете посмотреть как реализованы такие подходы на разрын фреймворках - они почти везде одинаковые. За пример можете взять популярный фреймворк Yii2. Могу так же посоветовать серию видео-уроков по написанию собственного фреймворка, в которых подбробно решается ваша проблема и + к этому вы поймете кое-что большее для себя, и узнаете что-нибудь новенькое :)

[Плейлист уроков](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGHfiWjIDr8&list=PLD-piGJ3Dtl1gX1wh22vBeeg6gMP1VlnW)

В вашем случае подойдет такой вариант:

```
<?php

    require_once('db.php');

    if($alias = isset($_GET['alias']) ? $_GET['alias'] : null
       && $page = R::find('pages', 'page_url = ?', [$alias])) {
        echo "<p>{$page->page_url}</p>";
    } else {
        exit("404 Not found");
    }

?>
```

Конструкцию `switch` можно не использовать, т.к. в вагем случае алиас страницы уникален.
Но я предпочел бы использовать "[Альтернативный синтаксис](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)" и выполнил бы вашу задачу так:

```
<?php

    require_once('db.php');

    $alias = isset($_GET['alias']) ? $_GET['alias'] : null;
    $page = R::find('pages', 'page_url = ?', [$alias]);

?>

<? if($page): ?>
    <p><?= $page ?></p>
<? else: ?>
    <p>404 Error - not found.</p>
<? endif ?>
```

Также вы можете настроить [ЧПУ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL) с помощью apache(.htaccess), а в php уже использовать регулярные выражения, чтобы обрабатывать ваш входной УРЛ.

Хорошего дня и успехов в программировании!

Comment: Я все понял, что вы имели ввиду. Какой момент вас смутил в моем ответе. Если это вывод 404 ошибки - это на ваше усмотрение, делать его или нет.

Comment: Сейчас посмотрю, и может исправлю ответ, постараюсь отвтеить)

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, но вместо find использовал findOne. Спасибо, заработало:

```
<?php

require_once('db.php');

    $alias = isset($_GET['alias']) ? $_GET['alias'] : null;
    $page = R::findOne('pages', 'alias = ?', [$alias]);
?>

<? if($page): ?>
    <p><?= $page ?></p>
<? else: ?>
    <p>404 Error - not found.</p>
<? endif ?>

------
Спасибо!
```

Comment: Пожалуйста ;) , можете так же поставить что мой ответ является решением))), если не трудно)

Comment: Так и сделал. Еще раз благодарю!